# Retrieve Notice from stored procedure in backend from postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, procedure

I'm using PostgreSQL with stored functions and PHP with PDO for the system.
Is there any way to catch `RAISE NOTICE "sometext here"` in PHP from the PostgreSQL? It will be really useful to me, if I can catch all notice for debug purpose.

Thank you for the answer/s/ and the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you cant do it directly, but.. As far as it is only for debug purpose, psql notices are captured by handler itself where when notice is issued php updates variable holding it and does not append the value to some array, as Kouber Saparev said in his post:
[Get all notices of PostgreSQL's RAISE NOTICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110093/get-all-notices-of-postgresqls-raise-notice)

You should better look for some php error handling functions if you need to catch it.

Comment: Thank you for the replay! Have no Idea how I missed this question.